# How to get Row where two Columns equal specific values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm very new and I'm trying to create a Time in/Time out sheet.  I have 2 separate sheets, first(ACTIVE) is where the trigger happens that starts the onEdit(e) script.  All the functions that start onEdit(e) affects the second sheet(PASSIVE) to fill out Columns A(Last Name), B(First Name), C(Location), D(Time Out).  I finished making the Time out functions by getting value of A, B, C + Active Row(this isn't the code).  The trigger is always on the same row as the values being copied, so it was relatively simple. On the PASSIVE sheet I have all the values being stored using a code someone made called addRecord where it gets last row + 1 of the PASSIVE sheet and installs the values grabbed from the ACTIVE sheet and plugs them in.  So it adds records without overwriting anything. Works beautifully.  However making a "time in" function has been difficult.  E(Time In) My idea is to getRow of the PASSIVE sheet by searching PASSIVE!A for the Value grabbed from (ACTIVE!A + Active Row) once it finds a match, it sees if (PASSIVE!E + the matched row) is empty.  If it is, it adds new.Date and finishes. If it isn't empty, it ignores this row and continues searching down the line for the next Row that has PASSIVE!A match the grabbed value.  Once it finds this Row, getRow. setValue of (PASSIVE!E + grabbed row, new Date())

I did find a function online to find the first row that matched the ACTIVE!A with PASSIVE!A.  But it kept overwriting the date on the first match.  It never ignored row with nonempty cell to the next match row.  Maybe I was just slightly off, which is why I'm asking for a lot of detail and explanation in the Answers. 
This was the Code I used from another answer.

```
function getCurrentRow() {
  var currentRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
  return currentRow;
}
function onSearch1()
{
```

What I added

```
  var row = getCurrentRow();
  var activeLocation = getValue('ACTIVE!A' + row);
```

Continued Other Code

```
 var searchString = activeLocation;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PASSIVE"); 
    var column =1; //column Index   
    var columnValues = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
  var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Row Index - 2
```

What I added

```
 setValue(PASSIVE!E + searchResult, new Date().toLocaleString())
```

It worked if everyone has a different name, but the search Result always found the first row of the match, I tried adding an if ACTIVE!A == PASSIVE!A 
 && PASSIVE!E =="", grabRow (I know this isn't proper code)  But I didn't even know where to put this if function or if it would work or if it would just keep coming up false after it runs the first time true.

Continued Other Code

```
if(searchResult != -1)
    {
        //searchResult + 2 is row index.
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PASSIVE").setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(searchResult + 2, 1))
    }
   if(searchResult = searchResult2) {
    setValue('PASSIVE!E' + searchResult, new Date().toLocaleString())
  }
}
Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if(this[i] == search) return i;

  return -1;
}
```

So this is what I used, but not sure if it's the right way to go about this.  Every time I used it, it would only set the SearchResult to the first row it found that had the searchString  I'd actually prefer if it found the last row, considering the add record goes down over time and signing in should be the most recent name.  But I'm guessing if I can just get a function that searches a range and finds the row for two values in specific columns, I can then just `setValue('PASSIVE!E' + foundRow, new Date().toLocaleString())`

Edit 5/9/2019 17:34 PST
Thank you to those Answering. I'm expanding on the question.

```
function rowWhereTwoColumnsEqual(value1,col1,value2,col2) {
 var value1=value1 || 'A1';//testing
 var value2=value2 || "";
```

The idea I'm having is to search Column1 of another sheet for, let's say, 'SheetA1' (the first sheet). And Column3 of another sheet for "" (cellisempty).

```
var value1= 'Sheet1!A1';
 var value2= "";
 var col1='Sheet2!A';
 var col2='Sheet2!C';
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
 var rg=sh.getDataRange();
 var vA=rg.getValues();
```

However, I don't know how the vA works. I also want to getRow() of the Row that is found in order to use that number in another function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function rowWhereTwoColumnsEqual(value1,col1,value2,col2) {
  var value1=value1 || 9;//testing
  var value2=value2 || 8;
  var col1=col1 || 1;//testing
  var col2=col2 || 2;//testing
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][col1-1]==value1 && vA[i][col2-1]==value2) {
      rA.push(i+1);
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(rA.join(','));
  //return rA;//as an array
  //return rA.join(',');//as a string
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.  I was just wanting clarification since I'm very new to Java. are the variables ```var value=value || 10;
  var col1=col1 || 1;
  var col2=col2 || 15;``` placeholders that can be changed with other values including words?  or must it remain for the function to work and instead type the values into the ```rowWhereTwoColumnsEqual(value,col1,col2)```? such as ```rowWhereTwoColumnsEqual(value,'first name', "")``` Also I might be reading it wrong, but the question I'm asking is to find two separate values in two separate columns that share a row.

Comment: I just use them when I'm testing the code.  If you provide those parameters then it will use what you provide.  If you provide no parameters then it will use those as the defaults. By the way, it's JavaScript not Java.  There's significant difference.

Comment: Okay I missed that

Comment: Okay, I changed it .

Comment: I like to drink my Script sometimes. XD

Comment: If you want the function to return the rows just let me know how you would like to receive the data.  A string is simple because you can turn them into an array with the split function. Unless there are commas in the values themselves.

Comment: Please do all of your code posting in your question.

Comment: So the issue I'm having now is typing in values, I've been testing it with a simple sheet.  However I might be typing the values in wrong.  It keeps giving me the Ui and saying the last row with nothing in it, instead of Giving me the Row I was expecting. I put ('name', 'A', "",'C')  Was expecting 1, but got 7 (I have 6 lines full)

Comment: I'm not clear as to what your asking.  Perhaps you should just ask another question.

Comment: I will ask another question, but I really do like the function you gave me, I think it's close to what I'm looking for, I just don't know all the technical stuff, so perhaps I'm typing it wrong.  I will be using the function you gave as the starting point to the next question because I'm sure it's very close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'll take a look at your new question.  Perhaps I can't help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069665/get-first-row-where-cola-name-colb-secondname-and-colc-nullis-empty 
link to new question.