# Get First Row where ColA = Name, ColB = SecondName and ColC = null(is empty)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm very new to JavaScript so bear with me. I want an equation that searches multiple columns for specified values, not the same value across all columns.  For example: ColA = James , ColB = Smith, ColE = ""(cellisempty) right?
Once it finds the first Row with that criteria, it gets that row to be used in another equation which would be `setValue(ColE + gotRow, new Date())` I'm making a Time in/Time Out Sheet if you are curious.  The Idea is the function searches for a person's name and for the next available space to place the time because the same person may have signed out and in multiple times on the same sheet.  Once he has the row with an empty spot it places in the current time on that row, which makes it no longer empty, meaning next time the function runs, it will skip that row and go to the next one the guy signed out of.

here is a function I was given to try out my problem thanks to one of the Users.

```
function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue()
}

function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function rowWhereTwoColumnsEqual(value1,col1,value2,col2) {
  var value1=value1;//testing
  var value2=value2;
  var col1=col1;//testing
  var col2=col2;//testing
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][col1-1]==value1 && vA[i][col2-1]==value2) {
      rA.push(i+1);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(rA.push(i+1))
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(rA.join(','));
}
```

I created a function below it, just for inputting values to see how it works

```
function getrowWhereTwoColumnsEqual(){
 rowWhereTwoColumnsEqual('James','Sheet1!A',null,'Sheet1!C')
Logger.log(rowWhereTwoColumnsEqual('Ta','Sheet1!A',null,'Sheet1!C'))
}
```

The sheet I made has `'James'` in A1 while C1 is empty. It also has 5 other rows full of random names.

```
Column A | Column B  | Column C
=================================
James    |     C     | 
Kyle     |     E     | 
Micheal  |     T     | 
Sarah    |     K     |
Tray     |     F     | 
John     |     D     |
```

So I was expecting to get a response "1" because row 1 should be true for both, but instead I saw "7". Probably because Row 7 is blank in all columns so all columns equal the same.  So I must have entered the values wrong, or the equation needs an adjustment. Like I said, I'm very new.
Edit 5/9/19 20:06
Thank you again Cooper. Your function works pretty well.

```
function test() {
  findRows(1,getValue('A1'),2,getValue('B1'),3,null,'Sheet1')
  Logger.log(findRows(1,getValue('A1'),2,getValue('B1'),3,null,'Sheet1'));
}
```

However, once I added values to C1, logger.log came up []

```
Column A | Column B  | Column C
=================================
James    |     C     | 5/9/19
Kyle     |     E     | 
James    |     T     | 
Sarah    |     K     |
James    |     F     | 
John     |     D     |
```

without the value, I received [1.0,3.0,5.0], but once I changed a value I received [] was expecting [3.0,5.0]

Edit 9:00 PST
I Changed the null to `""` and it seems to be working.

Edit 9:25 PST
Final Equations function Test() is the one that was finished product and succeeded.

```
function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue()
}

function getValues(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValues()
}
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function findRows(c1,n1,c2,n2,c3,n3,name) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][c1-1]==n1 && vA[i][c2-1]==n2 && vA[i][c3-1]==n3) {
      rA.push(i+1);
    }
  }
  return rA
}

function test() {
  var passiveRow = findRows(1,getValue('A2'),2,getValue('B2'),3,"",'Sheet1');
  Logger.log(passiveRow);
  setValue('C' + passiveRow, new Date().toLocaleString());
}
```

In order for "" to work Row 1 must have a header.  It Only works if there is only 1 result, which there should be in the end.  it finds the name and a blank spot to put the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

c1,c2 and c3 are column number n1,n2 and n3 are values or strings or null and name is the sheetname.

```
function findRows(c1,n1,c2,n2,c3,n3,name) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var rA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][c1-1]==n1 && vA[i][c2-1]==n2 && vA[i][c3-1]==n3) {
      rA.push(i+1);
    }
  }
  return rA
}

function test() {
  Logger.log(findRows(1,10,2,2,3,null,'Sheet150'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited Question to show you how it went.

Comment: `findRows(1,getValue('A1'),2,getValue('B1'),3,null,'Sheet1')` getValue() cannot be used this way.  getValue() is method of a Range. Not a standalone function.

Comment: I edited question to show I turned those into functions.  I think I found my problem with the [] I might have just been editing the wrong thing.  Had a Log and the function right next to each other and was editing the function but looking at the log which had an older copy of the function.

Comment: null still wasn't working, but I changed it to "" and it seems to be fine now.

Comment: Shoot, another problem arose.  if C isn't completely blank null gives [], so I used ''.  However, if C IS completely blank "" gives [].  I wonder if this could easily fixed just by having a header.  the answer is yes.

Comment: null works for me. Yeh, not completely blank is not null.

Comment: Adding the header was a good enough fix.  I plugged this function into my time out time out table and it works beautifully!  Love it! Thank you so much, you saved me so much headache!